# If $B/IB$ is Noetherian and $B/N$ is faithful, is $B$ Noetherian if we don't assume $B$ is finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $B$ be a $A$ module.Could you give a example of rings which satisfies the following condition, $1,2,3$.

1. $B$ is not Noetherian as an $A$-module.
2. If $I$ is an nonzero ideal of $A$, then $B/IB$ is Noetherian as an $A$-module.
3. If $N$ is nonzero subbed of $B$, $B/N$ is not faithful as an $A$-module.

If we add condition that $B$ is finitely generated over $A$, we can say there is no example which satisfies 1 and 2 and 3. But if we do not assume that, we may be able to find examples which satisfies 1 and 2 and 3.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such $A$-module exists. Indeed, we can show that if $B$ satisfies conditions 1,2,3 in the question, then $B$ is finitely generated. Let $0\ne x\in B$, and let $N=Ax$, the submodule generated by $x$. Since $N\ne 0$, the quotient $B/N$ is not a faithful $A$-module, by condition 3. Thus, there exists $0\ne a\in A$ such that $aB\subset N$. By condition 2, $B/aB$ is Noetherian, whence $B/aB$ is finitely generated. So, $B/N$ is finitely generated. Thus, in the following exact sequence$$0\to N\to B\to B/N\to 0$$both the left and right terms are finitely generated. Hence, $B$ is finitely generated.

It is known that no finitely generated $A$-modules satisfy conditions 1,2,3. See step 2 in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966662/ring-is-noetherian-if-it-admits-a-faithful-finitely-generated-module-with-acc-on). Also, note that the paragraph "A different approach" can be gently modified to answer this question without using the finitely-generated hypothesis.